# AddScoped service is not retaining settings throughout the request

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have created an Interface

```
public interface ICurrentUser
{
    Task<bool> Set(UserAuth user);
    User Get();
}
```

and a class

```
public class CurrentUserSvc : Interface.ICurrentUser
{
    private User _u;
    private UserAuth _ua;
    private AppDbContext db;

    public CurrentUserSvc(AppDbContext db) {
        this.db = db;
    }

    public User Get()
    { 
        return _u;
    }

    public async Task<bool> Set(UserAuth ua)
    {
        _ua = ua; // this is the default EntityFramework IdentityUser
        _u = await db.AppUsers // this is my applicaiton's 'extra settings'
                               // user used to ensure passowrd fields are
                               // not passed about everywhere
            .Where(u => u.UserID == _ua.UserID)
            .SingleAsync();
        return true;
    }
}
```

In `Startup.cs` I set

```
services.AddScoped<ICurrentUser, CurrentUserSvc>();
// I also add a service which will be used later in a scoped
// lifecycle (though I've also tried transient on that one)
services.AddScoped<IProductDbSvc, ProductDbSvc>();
```

Later I call to a piece of middleware:

```
    public async Task<Task> Invoke(HttpContext hc)
    {
        if (hc.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
            UserAuth iu = await _um.FindByIdAsync(hc.User.GetUserId());
            await _cus.Set(iu);
        }
        // the values are definitely set correctly here.
        // I have inspected them during debug
        return _next(hc);
    }
```

Later still I try to access the content of the `CurrentUserSvc` I try to access the current user via the GET

```
    public ProductDbSvc(AppDbContext db, ICurrentUser cu){
        this.db = db;
        this.cu = cu;
        // the values in cu are NULL here. Get() returns null
        this.CurrentUser = cu.Get();
    }
```

but the result of Get() is `null` I was expecting that a Scoped param would retain the values set earlier in the request lifecycle.

What am I missing? Is there some other way to ensure the scoped-singleton retains the user data throughout the application's lifecycle.

**UPDATE**:  I've created a generic project that illustrates this problem generically. https://github.com/AlexChesser/AspnetIdentitySample

- check out the repo
- build and run in visualstudio or DNX
- register a local user
- try to view the service on http://localhost:5000/api/currentuser

You'll notice that within the DEBUG output you can see that the correct user details are set, but within the actual controller itself the values returned are null.

**UPDATE 2** the working sample is on this branch in github https://github.com/AlexChesser/AspnetIdentitySample/tree/dependencyinjectionscoped

**UPDATE 3** turns out scoped parameters can be injected into the INVOKE method of custom middleware as well. https://github.com/AlexChesser/AspnetIdentitySample/commit/25b010a5ae45678c137b2ad05c53ccd659a29101 altering the invoke method will allow for scoped parameters to be injected correctly.

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext,
    ICurrentUserService cus,
    UserManager<ApplicationUser> um)
{
    if (httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        ApplicationUser au = await um.FindByIdAsync(httpContext.User.GetUserId());
        await cus.Set(au);
    }
    await _next(httpContext);
}
```

**UPDATE 4** - I discovered an issue with my middleware signature last night which is pretty important.  Code above has been edited to the correct form. Specifically the method was `Task<Task>` and `return _next(...)`

This was resulting in a "whitescreen" death on certain page loads (async called badly will not throw a stack trace)

By altering to a `Task` and using `await next(...)` the code functions properly and eliminates the intermittent whitescreen death caused by badly implemented async in dotnet5.

Comment: `if (hc.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {` may be user isn't setted due to this check? A suggest you use Logging in your application, that facilitate debugging.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that the is authenticated check does correctly pass and set the current user service's values as expected

Comment: @AlexC: As far as I can see from your code in the github repo, the `ICurrentUserService` is injected via constructor, but middlewares are instantiated only once i.e they are singleton, so instead of injecting there, try to `resolve` this service via the passed in HttpContext in the invoke method...you can use the `RequestServices` property to resolve it

Comment: Cool! How did you discover you can inject via `Invoke`?

Comment: @davidfowl told me in a comment on an issue over on github.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DbContext` is a scoped service and as well as your `CurrentUserSvc` is a scoped service. Middlewares are instantiated only once for the whole running time of the app, so they are singleton essentially. So you need to remove both `DbContext` and `CurrentUserSvc` from being constructor injected here.

Instead you can use `HttpContext`'s `RequestServices` property (which returns a `IServiceProvider`) to resolve both the `DbContext` and `CurrentUserSvc` services.

Comment: That's interesting. So even thou it is called on every request it is only ever instantiated once. That  makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Kiran! You were correct about the scoping issue and the RequestServices on the httpcontext.  https://github.com/AlexChesser/AspnetIdentitySample/commit/a0a129ee0f22514a25fcf0c8493aa731d03178b1 this commit contains the changes needed to make the currentuserservice work as I'd intended

Answer (score 1):

In the middleware, inject a dependency to `IServiceProvider`, rather than `ICurrentUser`.  Then in the `Invoke` get the current user via `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ICurrentUser>();`

Comment: unfortunately that didn't work. the values are still null later in the lifecycle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stafford! You were correct about the IServiceProvider requirement, but per Kiran's answer below, it was failing, I assume for the same reason as all other injection. Middleware is only instantiated once. The working resolution was to pull the IServiceProvider off of the HttpContext https://github.com/AlexChesser/AspnetIdentitySample/commit/a0a129ee0f22514a25fcf0c8493aa731d03178b1 working code viewable in github in this commit.